# Cruisecontrol build messages Date and Time of build incorrect

Tags: time, timezone, cruisecontrol

This may be a very simple fix but I can't seem to find how to set the time zone after a solid amount of googling. This is what we get in email letting us know if the build failed or was successful:

```
Date of build:
2011-05-24T00:59:44
Time to build:
17 minutes 26 seconds
Last changed:
2011-05-24T00:55:47
```

This build actually occurred at 6:20 pm. Any tips, help, or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

are you using .net cruisecontrol or the java version? We are using the java version and we also had the same problem.

Are you using the exec plugin to execute your builds? If yes then this is the problem. I wrote a specific plugin for our build environment and the time bug was gone. Now time is accurately displayed.